# How to pick multiple contacts using cordova contacts Plugin?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, contacts

I am using cordova contacts plugin accessing device contacts in ios and android. I am using the navigator.contacts.pickContact method pick the particular contact. but this method only select the single contact how to select the multiple contacts is possible or any other method is available?

Comment: hi did you ever get this working?

Comment: Hello , have you got any workaround for the same so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the navigator.contacts.find method. This executes asynchronously, querying the device contacts database and returning an array of Contact objects. The resulting objects are passed to the contactSuccess callback function specified by the contactSuccess parameter.

For more details https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts

Hope this helps.

Comment: Regretablly despite that the documentation says the "find" method, when returning "all" contacts, is *NOT* async. Try it. If you load lets say more than 500 contacts ...the UI freezes until all the contacts are retrieved.